# movement based on given angle (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

http://pastebin.com/3vwiTUyT

my code is here.
I would like to make krog1 move in the canvas based on the angle i set. I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/jinewevilu/edit I take it you mean something like this?

In the future, functioning examples are more helpful than just code.

As for your question, you'll need to do some trigonometry.

I see you have

```
krog1.x += krog1.power;
krog1.y += krog1.angle/3;
```

What you want is something more like this

```
krog1.x += krog1.power * Math.cos(krog1.angle/180 * Math.PI);
krog1.y += krog1.power * Math.sin(krog1.angle/180 * Math.PI);
```

[Wikipedia has more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry#Overview). In the above, `angle/180 * Math.PI` is used to convert from degrees to [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

Comment: woah thanks for so quick answer :D it work. I just have to put /-180. Because how canvas works with the coordinate system